# Retrieve Image and Title from URL Field in Wordpress ACF?

Tags: wordpress, url, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, title

I am new to ACF on Wordpress,

I am building a custom fields group which contains the following fields: title, url, image..etc..

I want both title and image fields to get replaced when placing a URL by the following:

1. Title retrieved from URL in Title Field (I can edit if I want to change)
2. Images retrieved from URL to select 1 Image as Featured Image and upload.